# Why I can't run this on jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm keep getting error why ? I tried everything, have removed every label and name tag. I know that there is similar questions being asked but non of them is useful to me. One of the answers for this particular error was to remove }) but I don't have any of those extra brackets. Thanks.

> {"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name':
>   u'initial-js_lib', 'form': , 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id':
>   u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field':
>   ,
>   'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name':
>   u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': , 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id':
>   u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field':
>   ,
>   'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}

And how to print my username and password ??

```
<form id='submit_leave_email' method = 'post'>
<input id='username' type='text' value='username'/> 
<input id='password' type='password' value='password'/>                         
<button type='submit' class='input_button' value='submit'>Insert </button>
</form>
<p> Text, please stay here</p>


    $('#submit_leave_email').submit(function() {

    var username = $('#username').attr('value');
    var password = $('#password').attr('value');



    });
```

Comment: There is nothing here that would indicate an error. Can you share the fiddle with us?

Comment: Why -1 ? I shared everything the error and my code. http://jsfiddle.net/QQGfc/385/  @JayBlanchard

Comment: What is that error coming from?

Comment: Why are you asking me about -1? I have no idea where that came from.

Comment: My apologies to You, I thought You gave it to me. @JayBlanchard

Comment: You cannot always assume that whoever comments on your posts will downvote or upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because jsfiddle does not offer a web server to handle your form submit. But if you just want to print the username & password you can use the `button type="button"` rather than `button type="submit"`. So it this way you can also avoid using `event.preventDefault()`,which infact prevent the default behaviour of the a HTML element.

HTML

```
<form id='submit_leave_email' method = 'post' >
<input id='username' type='text' value='username'/> 
<input id='password' type='password' value='password'/>                         
<button type='button' class='input_button' value='submit'>Insert </button>
</form>
<p> Text, please stay here</p>
```

JS

```
$('.input_button').on('click',function(event) {
    var username = $('#username').attr('value');
    var password = $('#password').attr('value');
   console.log(username , password)
 });
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/ug34xexz/2/)

Note: If your not using `$(document).ready(function(){..}` you have to wrap this js snippet inside body tag.

Also if you really need to submit the form then in real application you dont need to use `event.preventDefault()`.Also printing & consoling will take place actual form submit.

Here is a  [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/ug34xexz/1/).

Note:I just used action  tab and used `action = "www.google.com"`. You can check in console that before processing it is consoling the username & password

Answer (score 3):

The form submit is trying to hit a server when clicked it seems? If you prevent the default action it should work, fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/uL0ut0xk/

```
 $('#submit_leave_email').submit(function(e) {
     var username = $('#username').val();
     var password = $('#password').val();
     console.log(username);
     console.log(password);
     e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: Ok this helped with the jsfiddle but do I have to put e.preventdefault in real code or it is just the jsfiddle issue ? @brettkc

Comment: If you want to submit the form to your server using the form data you would remove that -- that's just for the jsfiddle.

Comment: @StefanJovanic depends on what you will be doing. If you are parsing the data with JS instead of posting it to something like a php page, then you will need the ` e.preventDefault();`.

Comment: Thanks I will post whole question because this helped me with jsfiddle but I cant find the answer I'm looking for. Thanks for your answer @hopkins-matt

Answer (score 1):

The error is generated because the form does not have the `action` attribute defined which tells where to post the data. Also, `jsFiddle` does not allow you to post data.

Comment: If I don't put method = 'post' then I get {"error": "Please use POST request"} @dxcorzo

Comment: if form does not have the `action` attribute, it will usually send back to the page itself

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code must be inside script tag, or add the javascript code to the javascript section

```
 <script>    
     $('#submit_leave_email').submit(function() {

    var username = $('#username').attr('value');
    var password = $('#password').attr('value');
    });
</script>
```